# Windows BLE GattValueChangedEventArgs.Characteristic.Value missing data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use windows BLE to connect and read from BLE barcode scanner. Everything works fine while the value I receive from the BLE device is only short string. If I scan a barcode which is more than 16 bytes, the GattCharacteristic.ValueChanged event fires multiple times, and each time I receive a chunk from the data. It would not be problem but I don't receive everything and parts are missing. I use identical method on Xamarin.IOS and the event raised once and I receive 1 long string containing the whole data. So it works in Xamarin.IOS but not in winform.net.
It seems windows uses about 16bytes IBuffer for GattCharacteristic.Value and while it raises the event, that buffer gets cleared and replaced with new data.

Is there any way to increase Windows BLE IBuffer size or tell windows to get the whole data together before raise the event?

What I should receive:

```
Collection: 1000
From: West Midlands
To: Distribution 
RaisedBy: holloway
Raised: 29/09/2021
Item: Camargue 572 4m - hometx44cama
SKU: 26479
Identifier: 174435
SubIdentifier: 21642727-6
Qty: 4.27
```

What I receive:

```
Collection: 1000
From: West Mid
land To: Distr
edBy: holloway 
ised: 29/09/20
21 Item: Camarg
ue 572 4m 
Identifier
: 174435
SubIde
ntifier: 21642
 4.27
```

The code:

```
            CurrentConnectedDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceid);
            GattDeviceServicesResult result = await CurrentConnectedDevice.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);

            var services = result.Services;
            GattDeviceService ScannerService = services.Single(d => d.Uuid == ScannerServiceUUID);

            var Characteristics = await ScannerService.GetCharacteristicsAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
            ScanCharacteristic = Characteristics.Characteristics.Single(c => c.Uuid == ScannerNotifyUUID);

            var status = await ScanCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
            ScanCharacteristic.ValueChanged += BarcodeScanned;

            private void BarcodeScanned(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
            {
                byte[] data;
                CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(args.CharacteristicValue, out data);
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `Buffer` constructor ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.buffer.-ctor?view=winrt-20348#Windows_Storage_Streams_Buffer__ctor_System_UInt32_)) you can pass the size of the buffer. In your implementation, you are using `args.CharacteristicValue` as the buffer. If you can control the value of `args.CharacteristicValue` then you can increase the buffer size, *or* you can pass in a `new Buffer` to the `CopyToByteArray` method.

Comment: The args.CharacteristicValue passed over by windows when it raises the event. The args.CharacteristicValue.Capacity is already set to 16bytes when the event raised. The sender is the characteristic itself so i tried to read it from that but it's value is 16 byte as well. Seems windows pre-set this somewhere but i cant find any properties or command to change it.